# mysqli is a not known class in a symfony controller

Tags: mysql, symfony

I decide to work with `Symfony` for three weeks, realizing a small projekt to test.
Inside a Controller I use MySQL native without Problems. Now I want to change to MySQLi and nothing runs.

Connecting to the DB with:

```
$mysqliName = new mysqli('localhost', 'user', 'psasswd,', 'database');
```

fails with:

```
"Class 'blabla\HaloBundle\Controller\mysqli' not found in /Applications/MAM.../HaloController.php"
```

I can run MySQL in a "normal" php, out of Symfony without problems. What must I do, that I can use the MySQLi Classes in a Controller?

Comment: What is "normal php"? Do you call this working code from cli?

Comment: Try using "new \mysqli(...);"

Comment: "normal" php means in a php script outside Symfony, but with the same php and Apache.

Comment: @HQarroum Is correct. It is looking for `mysqli` in the `blabla\HaloBundle\Controller` namespace. Prefix it with a backslash as `\mysqli` for the global namespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With \mysqli for the global namespace it works.